# PM2 environmental veriable is 'undefined' when use process.yml

Tags: node.js, config, pm2

My pm2 process file is as follows

```
apps:
  - script   : ./Api/app.js
    name     : 'api-proxy-app'
    instances: 2
    exec_mode: cluster
  - script : ./AppMW/appMw.js
    name   : 'middleware-worker'
    instances: 4
    exec_mode: cluster
    watch  : true
    env    :
      NODE_ENV: development
      DB_URL: some_dev_value
    env_production:
      NODE_ENV: production
      DB_URL: some_prod_value
```

I want to access the DB_URL in production environment.
I have started my process as follows

```
pm2 start process.yml --env production
```

and tried to access the DB_URL value like

```
console.log('debug',process.ENV.DB_URL);
```

but always getting 'undefined'. Even process.ENV.NODE_ENV shows 'undefined'!

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you leave off the `--env production` bit, do you get the development env values?

Comment: I have tried  without --env, which should return 'some_dev_value'.But still I receive 'undefined'.

Comment: maybe off-topic, are you logging in app or appMw? cause the env is applied to second app only